# Where can I see a full list of all of the Xbox games I own?

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-one, xbox-series-x-series-s

Since Xbox Live Gold offers free games I have collected a lot of downloadable games on my Xbox Live account. Looking on my console is not an option, since I don't currently have an Xbox 360, and the Xbox One only shows my Xbox One games.

Where can I see a full list of all of the Xbox games I own?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can view your purchase and download history for your account [on the Microsoft website](https://live.xbox.com/en-US/download/history). You can filter that list down to Arcade Games, or Full Games to view just the games you have got, or you can view the full list which includes things like apps and DLC.

Comment: Alternatively you can look at your games in the Xbox One and browse to the right to see all the games that are waiting to be installed. If you are a Preview member, due to backwards compatibility, it will also show your digital 360 titles. If you are not you will need to wait till fall for that feature.

Comment: This answer is now outdated. Viewing the link, you can not view xbox 360 games. Only XboxOne and PC.

Comment: so how can you view it now without logging inside your XboxOne?

Comment: This is no longer valid. This site now just directs you to install the Xbox app on your computer or smartphone, and the Xbox app, while it has a handy link to see "Games I Own", this list only shows 12 games for me, and I own far more than that.

Answer (score 5):

All given links now point to a landing page saying you should download the Xbox app on PC or your phone. Since the recent update of the Xbox app on iOS and Android I am able to see them indeed. There is no such section online.

After some searching however, I found a possibility on the Microsoft website (not Xbox) that shows your transaction history:
https://account.microsoft.com/billing/orders/?period=AllTime&type=All&filterChangeCount=0

I'm not sure how far this will go back in time, since I only started buying digital games 2 years ago. It is not a full library of your games, but at least you should be able to see if you own a specific game or not.

Comment: This section will show digital games you have physically purchased; it does not show you any game you own through the games for gold program

Answer (score 1):

I reached out to Microsoft through their support channels.

At present, there is no way to view a list of all of the games you currently own. Instead, you can look at available games on a specific console, and games you have deliberately purchased.

---

### View All Games That You Have Explicitly Purchased

You can view all of your Microsoft Store purchases through your order history, [found here](https://account.microsoft.com/billing/orders/?period=AllTime&type=Digital&filterChangeCount=2&continuationToken=). Make sure that you have *"Digital"* and *"All available"* selected from the left hand menu.

This will show you all digital purchases on record. I can personally go back as far as May of 2011; for me, at least, this represents my entire digital purchase history.

It will not show you games that you own through the Games for Gold program, as these transactions did not count as actual purchases.

### View All Games for a Specific Console

You can view all games available on a specific console by navigating to the *"Games & Apps"* tab on the specific console. You should be able to look at all available games, as well as  all of the games made available through the Games for Gold program.

As mentioned, this will show many games from other consoles, specifically when looking at the majority of the Xbox 360 titles that are compatible and can be installed to Xbox One and Xbox Series XS consoles. You may be missing the few titles that are not backwards compatible, in which case they will only show up on Xbox 360 consoles.

I do not personally own an Xbox Series XS console, so I am not able to test the theory, but you might also see your Xbox Series XS titles when viewing from the Xbox One; I can confirm that you can for Game Pass games, as I can view *"Medium"* despite the game only being available for Xbox Series XS.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you used to be able to simply go view them at https://account.xbox.com/en-US/MyGames?xr=shellnav and it seems that has now changed.

After a very long and exhausting (Norman P = 1/10 stars) chat with a Microsoft representative today I found out that they are having issues with the Market Place right now.

Under my transactions, I could not see any of my purchased Games With Gold games.